# CalendarArray get dates betweeen two Dates and skip a few

Tags: java, calendar, range, skip

i am trying to create an Array of Calendar Objects where i get all dates between start and end, while skipping the date "skip". So let's imagine i have the dates:

> start = 04.03.2016
>   skip = 21.07.2016
>   end = 02.03.2017

i tried something like this, but it didn't work that well:

```
public static Calendar[] getRange(Calendar start, Calendar skip, Calendar end){ 
    Calendar[] daysRange = new Calendar[100];
    Calendar placeholder = Calendar.getInstance();

    while(start.before(end)){
        if(placeholder.getTime() == skip.getTime()){
            continue;
        } placeholder.add(Calendar.Date, 1);
    }
    //(pseudocode)
    //add placeholder to daysRange
    return daysRange;
}
```

I would appreciate any tips on how i could continue.
Thanks!

Comment: I cannot more strongly advise against using the legacy `java.util.Calendar` class.  You should instead look in the `java.time` package for the most appropriate class for your use case.

Comment: I'll second what @JoeC said - the only thing worse what using `Calendar` is using `Date`. Avoid both at all costs. Also - with your current logic - what happens if there are more than 100 days in the range? What if there are partial days in the range?

Comment: I know you are right @JoeC but the thing is, the test i am trying to pass, expects me to return a  Calendar [ ].

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
while (start.before(end)) {
```

You never modify start or end, so the loop is endless.

Second: you use one placeholder object, that means that your whole array points to that one object, create a new Calendar for every step en the loop.

Third: don't use an array, use an ArrayList.